# Select запрос С++

Tags: c++, mysql

Есть `Select` запрос.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mdl_groups ... WHERE ... mdl_groups.name='Гр. №123'
```

Также, в конце, есть строковое выражение. Проблема в том, что запрос возвращает 0 строк, из-за того, что используются русские символы. Как можно решить эту проблему? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Надо чтобы:

1. Кодировка соединения соответствовала кодировке строки запроса.
   Т.е., например, при коннекте делать `SET NAMES utf8;` и в исходнике строка будет в UTF-8.
2. В БД должна быть корректно указана кодировка столбца. Иногда из-за кривых настроек там оказывается какая-нибудь Latin-1, тогда надо экспортировать данные, менять кодировку (в дампе и в БД) и импортировать их обратно (т.к. `ALTER` их «попортит», добросовестно пытаясь сконвертировать).